# Boost serialization stamp?

Tags: serialization, boost

when you try to serialize object data why do get `22 serialization::archive 7` in your serialized data? how do you get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late perhaps, but I was looking for the same thing so here goes =)

You should take a look at the `no_header` flag documented [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/archives.html#archive_models) and used like this:

```
using namespace boost::archive;

std::stringstream stream;
text_oarchive archive(stream, no_header);
archive << object;
```

I'm assuming text archives here judging from your question but the same works for the other archive types.

Obviously one should consider carefully before using this since the self-documenting property of the archive is largely lost for a modest saving in space...